# how to prove {(a^m)(b^n)(c^k): m!=k and m,n,k ∈ N} is non-regular?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, computer-science-theory

It's a question in CS courses "Theory of Computation", about proofs of regular or non-regular language.

How to prove {(a^m)(b^n)(c^k): m!=k and m,n,k ∈ N} is non-regular?

I try to solve it by pumping theorem but didn't work out.

Comment: Welcome to SO! From a mathematical point of view you should rather pay your question in math stack exchange ..

Comment: @Jib: [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com) is more appropriate.

Comment: The crux of a proof is: Regular expressions can be parsed with finite state machines. After parsing a^m, to accept c^k with m≠k, you must be able to distinguish m, so you must have a state for each possible m. But m ∈ N, so there are infinitely many possible values, so a finite state machine cannot have enough states.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your machine. There are two prefixes `a^i` and `a^j`, i≠j, that have to both go to the the same state, since you only have a finite number of states.  But then your machine can't tell the difference between `a^ibc^i` and `a^jbc^i`, one of which should pass and one of which shouldn't.